# How to send form data in httpsync - node.js?

Tags: node.js, http, http-method

I am using [httpSync](https://www.npmjs.org/package/httpsync) module to fetch data from the server.

I have sample as below

```
var httpsync = require('httpsync');
var req = httpsync.request({
             url: url,
             method: "POST"
});
```

#### Note:

```
   I am using httpSync because i want the request to behave synchronous.

   I cannot add original code
```

How can i send the form-data to the server using `httpSync`

I had tried the following but it is not working

```
  var req = httpsync.request({
             url: url,
             method: "POST"
             form:{a:1,b:1}
});
```

Any suggestion will be grateful

Answer (score 0):

httpsync module has an example for this.

Check this link

https://github.com/fengmk2/node-curl/blob/master/example/upload_file.js